# I am trying to call values from multiple textboxes and create a command line argument

Tags: c#, command-line, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

So far I have this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
var proc = Process.Start(psi);

string username = textBox1.Text;
string password = textBox2.Text;        //not sure about these 3 lines is correct?
string urladdress = textBox7.Text;

proc.StandardInput
        .WriteLine("program.exe URLHERE --username=****** --password=****** --list");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

richTextBox2.Text = s;
```

My problem is to get the it to create the command line like this:

```
program.exe https://website-iam-trying-to-reach.now --username=myusername --password=mypassword --list
```

Comment: And what problem are you having creating such a program?

Comment: i am not sure how to call the value from textbox1 2 or 7 in this line 
 proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("program.exe textbox7 --username=textbox1 --password=textbox2 --list");

Comment: What research have you done on how to concat strings together?  What information did you find, and how did it fail to solve your problem?

Comment: Well i am still a new to coding soi dont know what the procedure is called :) but i have pretty much tried googled everything that made sense for me and nothing showed up.. im am sorry if this irritates you but i am still trying to learn and this troubled me.. everything i found even remotly close was a console application but nothing that solved my problem and i am working on a form application.

Comment: You concatenate strings together in exactly the same way in a console application as you do in a winforms application.

Comment: i might not have been total clear in my explanation, the input in textbox1 is what i need where the ****** is located and so fourt with textbox 2 and 7. the --username is what the application send to the commandline hopefullt with my username after --username="here" 

But i will try to read about concatenate strings together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note

1. You dont need to call CMD.exe. You can call program.exe directly.
2. You dont need to use StandardInput.WriteLine() to pass arguments.

You can pass arguments as follows:

```
string username = textBox1.Text;
string password = textBox2.Text;        
string urladdress = textBox7.Text;

//Give full path here for program.exe
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("program.exe"); 

//Pass arguments here
psi.Arguments = "program.exe " + urladdress + " --username=" + username + " --password=" + password + " --list";

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";

var proc = Process.Start(psi);

//You might want to use this line for the window to not exit immediately
proc.WaitForExit();

string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

richTextBox2.Text = s;

proc.Close();
proc.Dispose();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! however i have to call cmd as program.exe is running in a commdo prompt!

Thank you very much! (y)

Comment: Glad i could help @heppaappeh